# Having problems running my unix ffmpeg script on windows

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

im trying to run this script for converting between the two formats of VR on a windows machine

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[0:v]crop=in_w/2:in_h:0:0 [top];
[0:v]crop=in_w/2:in_h:in_w/2:0[bottom];
[top][bottom]vstack,
scale=iw*min(2000/iw\,2000/ih):ih*min(2000/iw\,2000/ih),
pad=2000:2000:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[outv]"
-map "[outv]" -map 0:a -c:a copy output_3dv.mp4
```

from what ive found i think the \ characters need to be swapped with ^ like this

```
ffmpeg ^
-i input.mp4 ^
-filter_complex "[0:v]crop=in_w/2:in_h:0:0 [top]; [0:v]crop=in_w/2:in_h:in_w/2:0[bottom]; [top][bottom]vstack, scale=iw*min(2000/iw,2000/ih):ih*min(2000/iw,2000/ih), pad=2000:2000:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[outv]" ^
-map "[outv]" -map 0:a -c:a copy output_3dv.mp4
```

but its still falling over . would anyone have any pointers one where im going wrong please ?
thanks in advance

Comment: *"its still falling over"* is not a problem statement. You need to explain what you want to happen as well as describe the observed behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to have to guess what errors you are encountering:

- `Invalid size 'iw*min(2000/iw'` - Add single quotes around each expression.
- `Stream map '0:a' matches no streams. To ignore this, add a trailing '?' to the map.` Add `?` in your audio map to make it optional, as in `-map 0:a?`. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map).

Example command without the `^` and line breaks:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=in_w/2:in_h:0:0 [top]; [0:v]crop=in_w/2:in_h:in_w/2:0[bottom]; [top][bottom]vstack, scale='iw*min(2000/iw,2000/ih)':'ih*min(2000/iw,2000/ih)', pad=2000:2000:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 0:a? -c:a copy output_3dv.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks so much , that works perfectly. 
Apologies for the bad description l there were so many errors I didn’t know where to start.